# Get the nth absolute value in an array

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing

I'm looking to a fromula which gets the nth largest absolute value in a pivot table and its associated index (in excel). It works well when the value is positive but when the value is negative the output is wrong: "#N/A".

Here is my [pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4to6.png)

The formula I'm using:

```
{=INDEX($I$24:$I$37,MATCH(1,INDEX(($J$24:$J$37=LARGE(ABS($J$24:$J$37),ROWS(I$42:I42)))*(COUNTIF(I$42:I42,$I$24:$I$37)=0),),0))]}
```

When it comes to the 5th largest absolute value, I should get the following output: "AD" (which corresponds to this value: -13.4%) but instead I get: "#N/A
".

Comment: How should **ties** be handled??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to do this by listing the top n **numeric values** and then picking the corresponding text value, see screenshot example:

[image]

Formula in D2 is:

`=INDEX(A$2:A$10,SMALL(IF(ABS(A$2:A$10)=LARGE(ABS(A$2:A$10),ROWS(D$2:D2)),ROW(A$2:A$10)-ROW(A$2)+1),1+SUM(COUNTIF(D$1:D1,LARGE(ABS(A$2:A$10),ROWS(D$2:D2))*{1,-1}))))`

and formula in E2 is:

`=INDEX(B$2:B$10,SMALL(IF(ABS(A$2:A$10)=ABS(D2),ROW(A$2:A$10)-ROW($A$2)+1),SUM(0+(ABS(D$2:D2)=ABS(D2)))))`

both need to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down as far as required.

When there are ties, as with -4 and 4 in the example, then they are listed in the order they appear, hence -4 (A) is listed first, then 4 (E) then -4 again (J)

Comment: For the fomula in E2, you could simply use this formula:     ``=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$1000,2,FALSE),"")``                         and copied down.

Comment: VLOOKUP won't work if there are duplicates because it always returns the first match, so in the example above -4 is shown twice - using my suggestion you get both -4 codes from the table, "A" and "J" - VLOOKUP would return "A" twice

Answer (score -1):

Try this, entered as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
{=INDEX($I$24:$I$37,MATCH(lookupNthValue,RANK(ABS($J$24:$J$37),ABS($J$24:$J$37)),0)}
```

I will edit once you address how you want to deal with ties.

Comment: This formula does not consider absolute value of the data.

Comment: Disregard that, I misread the desired output, I assumed he wanted the negatives to be lower rank. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Still a few things wrong. 1) Why does your formula mix commas and semicolons? You should stick with commas because that is what the question asked, but if you are using semicolons, stay consistent. 2) Your cell ranges are different than that specified in the question. 3) Your formula still needs to incorporate `INDEX`. If you fix all of this I will remove the down vote.

Comment: Oops, probably didn't release shift a few times and typed semicolons